# Is there always some space around Flutter icons that cannot be removed (not IconButtons)?

Tags: flutter

I am using an Icon widget inline with Text widgets in a Row.  The Text widgets are next to each other with no spacing, but I cannot figure out how to force the same behavior for the Icon widget.

Note: I am not using an `IconButton`.  It's just an Icon widget.

I know this seems small, but I am trying to get things aligned.  Even if I just try to align the top of the Text widgets and the Icon widget, the Icon widget is slightly lower due to this seemingly impossible-to-remove spacing.

Am I missing something?

Notice that in the example, the Text widgets and the `SizedBox` widgets are right up against each other, but the Icon (`Icons.Square`) widgets have a gap.

I tried wrapping the Icon widget in a Padding widget

```
Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.zero, child: Icon(Icons.square))
```

But that didn't work any better.

[DartPad example](https://dartpad.dev/?id=d47d23676be94db82f3d49430a1a4ac5)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Example(),
    );
  }
}

class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: [
        const Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text('This is a test', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, backgroundColor: Colors.red),),
            Text('Here is more text with no spaces', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, backgroundColor: Colors.red),),
            Icon(Icons.square)
          ]
        ),
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Text('This is a test', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, backgroundColor: Colors.red),),
            SizedBox(width: 30, height: 10, child: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.zero, color: Colors.blue)),
            const Icon(Icons.square)
          ]
        ),
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Text('This is a test', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, backgroundColor: Colors.red),),
            SizedBox(width: 30, height: 10, child: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.zero, color: Colors.blue)),
            SizedBox(width: 30, height: 10, child: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.zero, color: Colors.blue)),
            const Icon(Icons.square)
          ]
        ),
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Text('This is a test', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, backgroundColor: Colors.red),),
            SizedBox(width: 30, height: 10, child: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.zero, color: Colors.blue)),
            SizedBox(width: 30, height: 10, child: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.zero, color: Colors.blue)),
            const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.zero, child: Icon(Icons.square)),
            const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.zero, child: Icon(Icons.add_circle)),
            const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.zero, child: Icon(Icons.add_circle)),
          ]
        ),
      ])      
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the built-in widget inspector, you will notice that there is no gap between the `Text` widget and the `Icon` widget. The gap is due to the design of the icon, not the `Icon` widget.

If you change the icon to `Icons.more_vert`, there will be a lot more space between the text and the icon. However, this has nothing to do with the space between the `Text` widget and the `Icon` widget. It simply because of the design of the icon.

widget inspector

[image: widget inspector]

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're dealing with alignment issues between Text widgets and an Icon widget within a Row. The Icon widget might have some inherent padding that's causing the misalignment. One way to address this is by adjusting the visualDensity property of the Icon widget.

In your Icon widget, you can set visualDensity to VisualDensity.compact to reduce the padding around the icon:

***Icon(Icons.square, visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact)***

This should help align the Icon widget with the adjacent Text widgets more closely. Try updating your code with this modification and see if it resolves the alignment issue in your layout.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before making any more posts, please familiarise yourself with the site rules, including the one [banning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) "AI" generated content.